# Given two points p and q on sigma, how many different lines (geodesics) join p and q? Consider the various cases for the positions of p and q.

Tags: geodesic, noneuclidean-geometry

Here, sigma is an arbitrary cylindrical space. I honestly have no idea where to even start. In my mind, there's only one geodesic connecting the points, because by definition a geodesic is the shortest path between two points...